# Get current url for a bundle with version information in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle

I'm trying to get the URL of one of my bundles with version information in C#.  The problem I'm trying to solve is that we have to host one of our pages in an iframe on a different server and we need to pass it the URL of any custom CSS  it should display.  I know the bundle base url but I don't know how to get the version information to pass to that page.

```
Styles.Url("~/css/someBundle").ToString();  //gets me the base url "/css/someBundle" in this case
```

I need to know how to get the portion that follows ?v={version information}

Answer (score 0):

Based on finding definition from an `@Scripts.Render(name)` in a Razor file here, it appears there is also a `Url` method:

```
public static class Scripts {
  [...]
  //
  // Summary:
  //     Returns a fingerprinted URL if the virtualPath is to a bundle, otherwise returns
  //     the resolve URL.
  //
  // Parameters:
  //   virtualPath:
  //     The virtual path.
  //
  // Returns:
  //     A System.Web.IHtmlString that represents the URL.
  public static IHtmlString Url(String virtualPath);
}
```

EDIT: Gave this a quick test: it does return the path, relative to the site root, so you need to convert to an absolute URL.